# how to apply css class to laravel collective select

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

i used laravel 5.3 for my project, i used laravel form collective into it code is below

`{{ Form::select('size', ['surat' => 'surat', 'mumbai' => 'mumbai','hongkong' => 'hongkong'], 'hongkong',['multiple'=>'true'], array('class'=> 'form-control') ) }}`

but the  `array('class'=> 'form-control')`  is not working for me if i removed `['multiple'=>'true']` then it work properly so how can i apply bootstrap class to my select box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
{!! Form::select('size', $citiesArray, 'hongkong', ['multiple' => 'true', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

You should pass `id`, `class` and other attributes in an array as 4th parameter.