# How to add CSS to Laravel Collective Form::select element

Tags: laravel

How to add css to Laravel Collective Form::select elemet in the following format

```
Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can class as fourth parameter like ['class' => 'your_define_class']

```
Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...'],['class' => 'your_define_class']);
```

Try this

Comment: Did this method work for u? I just found one which is working here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358271/how-to-apply-css-class-to-laravel-collective-select that is to use it within the 4th parameter.